# AudioKit "disconnected state" crash related to creation order of nodes in the chain

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am getting this crash using AudioKit `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'player started when in a disconnected state'` This happens when I create and add the nodes in one order but does not happen when I add them in another order.  Here is the desired chain:

[player]->[booster1]->[mixer1]->[booster2]->[mixer2]->[peak limiter]->[output]

When I build it in this order, it crashes:

```
let mixer2 = AKMixer()

let peakLimiter = AKPeakLimiter(mixer2)

AudioKit.output = peakLimiter
AudioKit.start()

let mixer1 = AKMixer()

let booster2 = AKBooster(mixer1)
mixer2.connect(input: booster2)

let booster1 = AKBooster(player)
mixer1.connect(input: booster1)

player.play()
```

But when I build it in this order, it works:

```
let booster1 = AKBooster(player)

let mixer1 = AKMixer()
mixer1.connect(input: booster1)

let booster2 = AKBooster(mixer1)

let mixer2 = AKMixer()
mixer2.connect(input: booster2)

let peakLimiter = AKPeakLimiter(mixer2)

AudioKit.output = peakLimiter
AudioKit.start()

player.play()
```

Any ideas why?  For dynamic reasons in the app, the first example (crashing) is the creation order that it needs.

What's also strange is that if I use the first creation order example and omit the 2nd booster, it works.  [player]->[booster1]->[mixer1]->[mixer2]->[peak limiter]->[output]

```
let mixer2 = AKMixer()

let peakLimiter = AKPeakLimiter(mixer2)

AudioKit.output = peakLimiter
AudioKit.start()

let mixer1 = AKMixer()
mixer2.connect(input: mixer1)

let booster1 = AKBooster(player)
mixer1.connect(input: booster1)

player.play()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may try to move `output` and `start`, just before `play` (but after all the `connect`):

```
AudioKit.output = peakLimiter
AudioKit.start()
player.play()
```

Comment: That worked.  However, because there are many instances of the first half of the chain ([player]->[booster1]->[mixer1]->[booster2]) which will be added by the user at runtime and connected to mixer2, I have to set the AudioKit output and start() AudioKit on app launch before users start adding.